# A Draggable bookmarklet that works when iframed to a page

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I can't seem to make my bookmarklet draggable when iframed.

```js
javascript:(function() {    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.chesscompass.com/analyze');  iframe.style.position = 'absolute';  iframe.style.top = '100%';  iframe.style.left = '100%';  iframe.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';  iframe.style.border = '2px solid red';  iframe.style.width = '60%';  iframe.style.height = '100%';  iframe.style.zIndex = '9999';  var closeButton = document.createElement('button');  closeButton.style.position = 'fixed';  closeButton.style.top = '5px';  closeButton.style.right = '5px';  closeButton.style.fontSize = '20px';  closeButton.style.color = 'white';  closeButton.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';  closeButton.style.border = 'none';   closeButton.style.borderRadius = '50%';   closeButton.style.width = '30px';   closeButton.style.height = '30px';   closeButton.style.cursor = 'pointer';   closeButton.style.zIndex = '10000';   closeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {    iframe.remove();    closeButton.remove();  });  document.body.appendChild(iframe);  document.body.appendChild(closeButton);})();
```

I tried to add a element to make that work but it didn't.